# How can I OR every element in two dimensional array in one clock cycle? Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

wire [a-1:0] array [b-1:0];

How can I OR the b array elements and get an a bits result in 1 clk?
Thank you

Comment: Use the OR reduction operator: `a=|b;`. See [this](https://www.utdallas.edu/~akshay.sridharan/index_files/Page5212.htm)

Comment: Thanks for advice. That is a bit-wise OR, however what I'm trying to do is Element-wise OR of the two dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Verilog ways:

```
reg [a-1:0] or_of_array;
integer i;
always @* begin
  or_of_array = array[0];
  for(i=1; i<b; i=i+1) begin
    or_of_array = or_of_array | array[i];
  end
end
```

SystemVerilog way:

```
logic [a-1:0] or_of_array;
always_comb begin
  or_of_array = 0;
  foreach(array[i]) begin
    or_of_array |= array[i];
  end
end
```

SystemVerilog also supports `wire [a-1:0] wire_or_of_array = array.or();` but may not be supported by all synthesizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use a loop to or each element with previous element.

```
wire [a-1:0] op;

// Inside an always block
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
  op = op | array[i];
```